# Locale Setting in Android

Tags: android, locale

What is the difference between locales ja and ja_JP in Android? Do I have to care about both?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the definition what the difference is:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html

ja = japanese
ja_JP = japanese as spoken in Japan

easy is if you just implement for the local ja for everyone speaking japanese no matter where they live.